# Bring already stoped existing activity to front

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

I have activity shows data for particular city, when the user navigates between cities I want to bring already opened activity for that city to the front if exists not to create a new one.

for example:

- The user open activity class name CityActivity for (X city info).
- Then inside (X city) he opened another CityActivity for (Y city info).
- Then inside (Y city) he opened another CityActivity for (Z city info).

Now inside (Z city) CityActivity if he clicks on a button to open (X city info) I need to check if there is another CityActivity for X city and bring it to front else create it.

I want a solution for that scenario not changing it with fragments or anything else.

If Android does not support a method to do so, how to bring an Activity from its reference to the foreground,something like :

```
mCityActivity.foreground();
```

or

```
context.toForeground(mCityActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this flag: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this,
       anotherActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note that all classes are from the same instance, so using this flag will bring most recent instance to the front which is not the specific instance that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this like that. As you've already noted, Android can't locate a specific instance of an `Activity` if you have multiple instances of the same `Activity` within your task. Your architecture is flawed anyway, as it is not scalable and you've already seen that you can't do what you want to do.

The correct way to do this is not to create multiple instances of your `Activity` at all. When the user wants to go from X City to Y City you should just change the data in the existing instance of the `Activity` from showing X to showing Y. Use an internal stack to remember the navigation and push an object representing "X" onto the stack. Now, when the user moves from Y City to Z City you push an object representing "Y" on to the stack and load the data for Z City into the views. When the user presses the BACK button. you simply pop the top object off the stack and use that to load the data for the previous City into the views again. When the user presses BACK and the stack is empty, you just call `finish()` on the `Activity`.

This architecture is completely scalable. The user can traverse as many cities as he wants to and even go back and forth between 2 cities numerous times. You will never have a memory leak or a stack overflow as you only ever have one instance of the `Activity`.